# saving data in javascript classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch, es6-class

I'm fetching data from an API and save it in a class.  When I'm trying to output the data in functions it give me an error of `undefined`, but when I call it in the console i can get the output.

```
class Api{
    GetAllRates(){
        async function getData(){
            const Data = await fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?`);
            const JData = await Data.json();
            return JData
        }
        getData()
            .then(data=>{
                this.Jdata = data;
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
    makeUi(){
        Ui.compareSection(this.Jdata); // TypeError: data is undefined //
    }
}
```

I also tried this but I get the `{ }` as the output

```
class Api{
    constructor(){
        this.Jdata = {};
    }
    GetAllRates(){
        async function getData(base=`EUR`){
            const Data = await fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?`);
            const JData = await Data.json();
            return JData
        }
        getData()
            .then(data=>{
                this.Jdata = data;
            })
            .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
    makeUi(){
        Ui.compareSection(this.Jdata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `.compareSection()` method defined? Also is `UI` another class?

Comment: yes, it is a static method from another class.

Comment: Where are `getAllRates()`  and `makeUi`  called? The former needs to return a promise, the latter needs to wait for that.

Comment: problem was i was trying to save a promise, i should destructure it first and then assign it to a variable.